# Restore database programmaticaly for a persistence.xml in Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, jpa, wildfly

I have a persistence.xml configured to drop and create de database. But I want to drop and create de database without redeploying or restarting the server. Just calling a function. Is that possible?

I'm using Wildfly 16 server with the provided hibernate.

Answer (score 1):

Use standart JPA function `Persistence.generateSchema` on existing persistence unit.

```
    HashMap m = new HashMap();
    m.put("javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action", "create");
    Persistence.generateSchema("pu", m);
```

By specifying action drop or create DB schema.